# styling the background of a div in a el function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have this el function in inside a wordpress block.
This code is inside the `save:function(props){`

```
el( 'div', { className: 'col-12 col-md-6 bg-green '},
```

I want to style it's background inline.

```
el( 'div', { className: 'col-12 col-md-6 bg-green ', style:'background-color: red;'},
```

I have a reason for this. After this step i want to replace the "red" with the user inputted color code like: #5a6644.

The problem is in the front end the background color of the div becomes red. 
But in the gutenberg editor the blocks says this:

```
this block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Incorrect syntax. "style" is object. Use - style: {backgroundColor: '#fff'}

Comment: Could you share your block code ?